# sort same elements of vector in ascending order

Tags: c++

```
bool third_parameter(const pair<long long,long long> &a,
                       const pair<long long,long long> &b)
    {
        return a.second>b.second;
    }

int main (){
        sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), third_parameter );
    return 0;
    }
```

I use this sorting technique up here, but this doesn't guarantee me anything when it comes to same elements of the vector. I am using a vector of pairs which has an increasing number i in .first and an int in .second. I want when it finds two equal .second elements to sort them in ascending order of .first.

Comment: Believe us, this has nothing to do with C. Don't re-add the tag, please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::tie` can still be used in that case, just care to order variables correctly.

```
bool custom_compare(const pair<long long, long long> &a,
                    const pair<long long, long long> &b)
{
    return std::tie(b.second, a.first) < std::tie(a.second, b.first);
}

std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), custom_compare);
```

Another option as we use integral is that "descending order for x" is "ascending order for -x":

so

```
bool custom_compare(const pair<long long, long long> &a,
                    const pair<long long, long long> &b)
{
    return std::make_tuple(-a.second, a.first) < std::make_tuple(-b.second, b.first);
}
```

Comment: @James Note that if you wanted to compare `first` then `second` you could just compare the pairs directly with `a > b;`. `std::tie` pretty much makes a new `pair` (really a `tuple<long long, long long>` which behaves similarly) but in this case flips `first` and `second`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood exactly the question, but it seems like the members of `a` should be tied together while the members of `b` should be tied together. `std::tie(a.second, a.first)` etc.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: As I understand, OP wants descending second and then increasing first.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure this produces a strict ordering. Maybe reversing `.first`'s sign instead would work while tieing the members of a pair together.

Comment: I like the second approach, the first however doesn't look intuitive to me.

Comment: @JVApen: I agree, but not all type can use unary `-`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux If you convert it to the equivalent `if (cmp(x, y) != 0) return cmp(x, y);` chain it becomes clear that it is indeed a strict ordering just like the original one, just with the priority and direction of ordering of the members mixed up.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: irreflexivity, and asymmetry seems trivial. remain transitivity: `x < y` and `y < z` -> `x < z`, so with `{y.s, x.f} < {x.s, y.f}` and `{z.s, y.f} < {y.s, z.f}`, do we have {z.s, x.f} < {x.s, z.f} ? We have `z.s <= y.s <= x.s` (`<=` as above comparaison will use second value on tie). if `z.s < x.s`, job done, else `x.s == z.s == y.s`, so `x.f < y.f < z.f`, good too.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: the question is: I am trying to sort a vector of pairs by the .second element. My previous algorithm was ok, but we can't be sure what it does when two .second elements are equal. Whenever this happens I want to sort these elements in ascending order by the .first element

Answer (score 1):

`std::sort` requires you to define a less than operator.
The trick to put in in code how 2 elements behave to each other.

```
bool third_parameter(const pair<long long,long long> &a,
                   const pair<long long,long long> &b)
{
    if (a.second != b.second)
         return a.second > b.second;

    // When second is equal, sort based on first, largest values first
    return a.first < b.first;
}

int main (){
    sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), third_parameter );
    return 0;
}
```

I do recommend renaming the method to something more expressive.

Comment: What an illogical sorting, fixed

Comment: Oh that seems good. Is it the best solution as for run time though?

Comment: How about you test it and let us know? Without measuring, you won't know. Though I use this way of coding in production by default.

Comment: I suspect similar performance but as always measure to know. Else choose the more readable for you.